# Call inner class in c#?

Tags: c#, call

I have an outer class with an inner class like this :

```
class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public int number;
    }
}
```

I think inner class is useful because I can call my "`number`" field like this : 
`A.B.number = X;`  but I can't call it this shape ! 
I create an instance from `A`, for example => `A a = new A();`
I want to access `B` by a instance directly => `a.B.number;`
but I can't.
I know if I create a new from `B`; I can access it, But I want to know how I can call my field in this shape => `A.B.number` NOT `b.number`
in brief, how I can access `B` class by call `A` class. (not directly `B`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the `B` class description in `A` you can just put a property in `A` that is of type `B`.

```
public class B 
{
    public int number;
}

public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        MyB = new B();
    }

    public B MyB { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
A myA = new A();
int num = myA.MyB.number;
```

Though I would suggest also making `number` in `B` a property as well.

Comment: Thanx for answering. my problem is solved.
use inner classes was incorrect for my purpose.
but a question, whats { get; private set; } usage here ? 
when i want to call my class, it has wrench icon, but when i delete this line, it has a blue cube icon, whats wrench type ? :-D

Comment: @3Dmajid That's a auto-impleented or automatic property.  It let's you create a property without having to create a backing field for it.  The `private` on the `set` means that it is read-only (can only be set from within the class).  That makes the class immuteable.

Answer (score 0):

Class `A` will not automatically instantiate an instance of class `B`. You would need to create a property that returned an instance of `B`.

For example

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        this.MyB = new B()
    }

    public B MyB {get; set;}
}
```

You could then delegate to `B` if you wanted to get a property of b directly.

```
public int BNumber 
{
    get
    {
        return MyB.number;
    }
}
```

With that said, why do you want a nested class here? Class `B` doesn't need to be nested in `A` for `A` to have a property of type `B`. I think you may be conflating class definition with property definition.

Comment: Thanx for answer my friend.
But why i need nested class ?
i have a main class named "MyProjectName", i have a lots of methods and fields in this class, but i like to category my methods ... For example if i want to use an animation method, i call "MyClass.Animation.PlayAnim()" instead "MyClass.PlayAnim()" ... this is all of my reason :-D ... so whats the best way ? inner class isn't correct for this ?

Comment: @3Dmajid If you just want to organize your code you should look into using namespaces for that.

Answer (score 0):

An inner class is just a class, and if you want to refer to its properties you need to have an object of that.

I think,you should make an object of B.

```
class A
{
    public B b = new B();

    public class B
    {
        public int number;
    }
}
```

I wrote this answer to take experts opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
   public B b{ get; private set; }


     public A()
    {
        b= new B();
    }


    public class B
    {
        public int number;
    }
}

A a = new A();
```

Now you can **access**

```
a.b.number;
```